# Insert data in comboBox from database

Tags: c#

I want to add all Id from customer table in combobox using class and this is my connection class [connectionClass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aStCP.png) in which I made a function for selecting data from databse. 
The second is my Customer form(this is customer form coding [customerForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HR9qO.png)) in which i call a function which i made in connection class .
but it only showing the last id in customer form and i want all id in combobox

Comment: Are we supposed to use our imaginations on what the code looks like and how to help you figure it out? Some example code is required here...

Comment: You're looping through a reader and returning id after that loop is done. (ie, the last id in the query result). Either store and return a list to be used to fill the combobox's item collection or fill and return a dataset/datatable and assign it as the datasource for the combobox.

Comment: Please put your codes directly here instead of its images.

Answer (score 0):

In the select() method you are returning a string,instead of that you need to populate
dataset and bind the data to combobox.

```
        reader = sc.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("customerid", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("contactname", typeof(string));
        dt.Load(reader);
```

regards
chandra

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `string` return a `List of strings` as follows:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Fill_Combo();
    }

    public void Fill_Combo()
    {
        Connection2DB cst = new Connection2DB();
        cmbBoxId.Items.AddRange(cst.Select().ToArray());
    }
}

class Connection2DB
{
    public List<string> Select()
    {
        var ids = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            string sqlqry = "select ID from Customer";
            SqlCommand cmds = new SqlCommand(sqlqry, _con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmds.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                ids.Add(dr["ID"].ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle exception here
        }
        return ids;
    }
}
```

Comment: this function only returning only ID from Customer table. I want to multiple data from Customer table using same method. Can you help me in this one??

Comment: How do you want to use these multiple data from Customer table? You can do this in different ways.

Comment: i want to use these data in a text field

Answer (score 0):

> this function only returning only ID from Customer table. I want to multiple data from Customer table using same method. Can you help me in this one??

Normally, this is not how this site works. First, you should ask a specific question, and show what you have done. Then we may help you.

Here I will try to give you two general solutions for working with a database.

**Solution 1:**

Let`s say you want to display everything retrieved from the database to your windows form.

First, create the `DataGridView` object let's call it `dataGridView1`. You can create it using the designer as any other control. then use the codes below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = GetData();
    }

    public DataTable GetData()
    {
        string ConStr = " your connection string ";  // Write here your connection string

        string query = @"SELECT * FROM Customer";   // or write your specific query

        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = null;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            // create data adapter
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            // this will query your database and return the result to your datatable
            da.Fill(dataTable);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Cannot read database: {ex.Message}");
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();

            if (da != null)
                da.Dispose();
        }
        return dataTable;
    }
    public void FillDataGrid()
    {
        Connection2DB cst = new Connection2DB();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = cst.GetData();
    }
}
```

**Solution 2:**

Let's say from your database table you want to extract 3 columns: `ID (INT)`,  `Name (VARCHAR(100))` and `Value (VARCHAR(MAX)`.

First, create a class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Nmae { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Create the function which returns the list of Customers:

```
public List<Customer> GetCustomers()
{
    var customers = new List<Customer>();

    try
    {
        string sqlqry = "SELECT ID, Name, Value FROM Customer";
        SqlCommand cmds = new SqlCommand(sqlqry, _con); // here _con is your predefined SqlConnection object
        SqlDataReader dr = cmds.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            customers.Add(new Customer
            {
                ID = (int)dr["ID"],
                Nmae = dr["Name"].ToString(),
                Value = dr["Value"].ToString(),
            });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle exception here
    }
    return customers;
}
```

Then you can use this data as you want. For example, to fill your `ComboBox` with IDs you can use this:

```
public void Fill_Combo()
{
    var customers = GetCustomers();
    var ids = customers.Select(x => x.ID.ToString());
    cmbBoxId.Items.AddRange(ids.ToArray());
}
```